# creating a string for a link in grails without g:link

Tags: grails, gsp

In a tag like below:

```
<a data-url="/new/request/showText/${requestInstance.id}"> view text</a>
```

Is there a way to not hardcode the url like I have?

I tried using `<g:link action="showText" id="${requestInstance.id}">` but that renders to an anchor tag.

What I'm doing might be find but I'm just curious if there is a better way to do this in grails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use

`${createLink(action:'myaction',params:[datasetId:dataset.id])}`

for full control. It just returns something like `http://myapp/myaction/123` and supportsall the params which `g:link` supports.

To be more specific:

```
<a data-url="${createLink(action:'showText',id: requestInstance.id)}"> view text</a>
```

should work.

Comment: For contexts other than controllers and GSPs (i.e. anywhere taglib calls aren't possible) it's worth knowing about the [grailsLinkGenerator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#webFeatures) Spring bean: `grailsLinkGenerator.link(...)` does the same job as `createLink(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `createLink` function inside of `${..}`.

So in your case this would be:

```
<a data-url="${createLink(controller: 'yourController', action: 'yourAction', params:[param1: 'value1'])}"> view text</a>
```